# How to Remove ~ character from asp HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have problem how to remove /~/ character from when I save file into database my problem is when they are no file into file upload controller I grape  the NavigateUrl form asp hyper link and add to savePath to save it but I get exception it couldn't find the directory

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ideaPark\DesktopModules\ResourceModule\pdf_resources\~\DesktopModules\ResourceModule\pdf_resources\New Text Document.txt'.

```
//save pdf docs 
String savePathPDF_Resouce = @"~/DesktopModules/ResourceModule/pdf_resources/";
String savePathPDF_Vocab = @"~/DesktopModules/ResourceModule/pdf_resources/";
if (fuPDFDoc.HasFile || fupdfVocabularyURL.HasFile)
{

    String fileName = fuPDFDoc.FileName;
    String fileName_Vocab = fupdfVocabularyURL.FileName;
    savePathPDF_Resouce += fileName;
    savePathPDF_Vocab += fileName_Vocab;
    fuPDFDoc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePathPDF_Resouce));
    fupdfVocabularyURL.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePathPDF_Vocab));
}
else
 if (!fuPDFDoc.HasFile || !fupdfVocabularyURL.HasFile)
{

    savePathPDF_Resouce += hl_doc_res.NavigateUrl.ToString();
    savePathPDF_Vocab += hl_doc_vocab.NavigateUrl.ToString();
    fuPDFDoc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePathPDF_Resouce));
    fupdfVocabularyURL.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(savePathPDF_Vocab));
}
```

Comment: can't you do a `string.Replace("~",string.Empty)` on the `String savePathPDF_Resouce and String savePathPDF_Vocab` if the Directory exist on the WebServer in terms of `Virtual Directory` you do not need to pass the '~' in the save path or you can use the `~` if you utilize the `Server.MapPath` Method for example `string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), FileUpload1.FileName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this to get the path:

```
// root filesystem path for the application (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ideaPark)
string virtualPathRoot = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

// path relative to the application root (/DesktopModules/ResourceModule/pdf_resources/)
string relativePath = savePathPDF_Resouce.TrimStart("~");

// save here
string targetPath = Path.Combine(virtualPathRoot, relativePath);
```